# Inserting many data into SQL Server in one stored procedure results in a huge amount of memory usage of the executing process

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am importing 300 MB data with table-valued parameters into the SQL Server database with a stored procedure. But then I noticed the process/executable that executs the stored procedure causes a 2 GB memory usage. And this usage stays like this for up to hours then it drops again.

Is it proportion normal?

I assume to be able to rollback, the database has to do a lot of copies and bookkeeping? Also the data is just many many small records, so that is also a reason?

If it's not normal, something else might be configured wrongly?

Comment: Without seeing what the procedure is doing it's almost impossible to comment, the are a multitude of possibilities; SQL Server will use as much ram as you allow it which is normal, how are you determining this procedure alone is responsible?

Comment: @Stu The procedure is just inserting some rows, I will try to update the post later cause I don't have it right now. When I insert much smaller records, this does not happen. I tried to comment out the procedure execution part, this does not happen neither. So I guess the execution is the only cause for this memory usage.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't release RAM after it's claimed it either, so if the RAM usage dropped it's because the service has restarted. As for it using 2GB of RAM, that is literally *nothing* for a SQL Server instance.

Comment: @Larnu I see. But if the process that executes the sql has 2 GB memory usage(not the sql server itsself), that should be also ok? Sorry I did not describe it detailly in the original post, I made a update.

Comment: What do you mean by the process that executes the process then?

Comment: @Larnu I mean the running service/process/executable that collects the data and calls the microsoft sql API, then executes the stored procedure.

Comment: So just to confirm, you're talking about the client-side process that reads the data file(s) and invokes SQL Server to insert the rows? Without seeing any code presented in the question I'd be recommending a code review: look for any usages of `IDisposable` classes that aren't wrapped in `using` blocks, e.g.: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` as well as any files/classes used to read in the data; consider putting in a call to `GC.Collect()` somewhere that's called on a low frequency (e.g.: minute or hour intervals) to force .NET to do mark-and-sweep garbage collection.